# Error: Module build failed when serving or building angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just installed the latest @angular/cli, and created a new angular project, but whenever I ran

`ng serve` or `ng build`

I'm getting the following error:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   1.50 MB | 
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 333.15 kB | 
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 230.44 kB | 
main.js               | main          |  48.01 kB | 
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.51 kB | 

                      | Initial Total |   2.10 MB

Build at: 2023-07-06T11:49:42.899Z - Hash: 98295fb6be6a8b7e - Time: 1608ms

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: /Users/user1/Projects/Angular Projects/ng-test/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: /Users/user1/Projects/Angular Projects/ng-test/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ng-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

I tried deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` again but no luck.